# Для чего предназначен: namedb.execute("VACUUM") в sqllite?

Tags: python, sqlite, python-3.x, sqlite3

Для чего предназначен: `namedb.execute("VACUUM")` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

После выполнения DELETE размер файла не сокращается, выполнение VACUUM пересоздаёт базу, в результате чего освобождается неиспользуемое пространство.

- https://habrahabr.ru/post/172085/
- https://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html